# NoSQL FREE alternative (alternative to ravendb) for C# development

Tags: c#, licensing, nosql

I discovered raven-db and I liked it but then I saw the license... GPL or Pay

So I'm looking for good free for closed-source C# development raven-db alternative. 
Seems like MongoDB and Berkley are GPL too.

And it's much better for me to find an embedded solution.

Comment: What is wrong with gpl license? aint it free then?

Comment: it's not free because I can't write opensource by corporate rules

Comment: You can directly use Lucene.Net(Apache License) which is used by ravendb

Comment: @L.B What is Lucene.Net?

Comment: [It](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) is the c# port of [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) to store/index/search text like a single table db. And it is a single .dll to use as an embedded library

Comment: @L.B is there some documentation for it?

Comment: It is one-to-one port of Lucene.Java. Therefore you can use any docs of java. For ex, http://blog.inflinx.com/2008/09/08/getting-started-with-lucene-part-1/ or http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/09/02/lucene.net-your-first-application.aspx

Comment: @Alessa i got you, missed the closed source requirement, as others suggest you can get the apache licensed mongodb or couch. I would suggest you to take a look at [Redis](http://redis.io/) and [memcached](http://memcached.org/) both which cover the BSD licensing, probably the most open of all licenses. Especially the former

Comment: For now I want to try couch-db (but first Lucene (because it's embedded) (I really feel frustrated when see mongodb logo, this brown color got only one association in my mind) Interesting if Redis could be embedded. Gods... memcached is using same color as mongodb around their logo. I can't use technologies with such color around >_< it's my psychological barrier.

Comment: [linqdb](https://github.com/ren85/linqdb)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you can [safely use MongoDB](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/103832439/the-agpl) with it's double core/driver license model.

And one more thing, AFAIK unless your code released to a "world" you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Be careful - especially with GPL databases and what it means to "link" your code.  Your code may have nothing to do with the database, but your hand is forced on licensing if you ever "distribute" your code.  The definition of "distribute" can be ambiguous, especially on the web.  When it comes to things like databases and GUI widgets, LGPL is a safer bet.

Comment: Yup. My company is "shipping" mongodb as part of a linux VM to a customer site and according to lawyers that prevents us from using MongoDb without enterprise licenses for EACH deployment... It's insane.

Answer (score 5):

Like RavenDB and MongoDB, **CouchDB** is a *document store noSQL database* with REST Api (so you can used with any language).

But CouchDB is under Apache 2.0 that can be used on commercial/closed project

Comment: What kind of nosql database are you looking for, except embedded possibility ? Just Document oriented or not ?

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/mcintyre321/PieDb is a very basic MIT-licenced embedded document db wot I wrote

It

- writes objects to app_data using json.net serialized documents
- uses Lucene.Net.Linq to provide basic IQueryable support
- optimistic concurrency
- requires no configuration

It would be nice to get some other developers behind it, as it's only had about a weekend of work on it, but it works for simple cases as a RavenDb replacement.

Comment: Hello, why not just use Lucene.Net?

Comment: Instead of a database you mean? Or for querying? Lucene.Net.Linq is an IQueryable provider, it uses Lucene.Net under the hood.

Comment: I mean instead of database.

Comment: I wanted to support a lot of features (like optimistic concurrency, customisable serialization, id generation), and I wanted it to feel similar to RavenDb (I wrote it after looking at the licensing page!).

Answer (score 3):

[iBoxDB.net](https://iboxdb.codeplex.com/) is a lightweight embeddable nosql database with transaction support. 
it can embed in net application, windows phone, mono application, unity3d, node.js

Answer (score 0):

Being GPL doesn't mean you can't use it in a closed source project, unless you plan on modifying the source.

EDIT: To be clearer - the key thing here is the distribution of any changes. You can use GPL software and do whatever you like to it in-house, but you cannot distribute binaries of these changes without also making the source available (unless you have reached an agreement with the copyright holder).

I don't know anything about raven-db, but I imagine it boils down to one of the following scenarios:

1. Your application interfaces directly with the source. If your application cannot build without the GPL project, then either your application must be licensed under the GPL, or you need permission from the copyright holder. LGPL is different, but you stated GPL in your question.
2. Your application can build without the GPL software, but needs it to run. This would be like me building an application on top of MySQL, and instructing customers to configure a MySQL instance themselves.

Comment: IANAL, but AFAIK, it is totally OK to modify GPL'd source code and not publish the modifications under the GPL, as long as your application is not distributed. If an application that uses GPL'd libraries is distributed, the GPL is "viral" and the whole application needs to be put under the GPL. If the application stays in-house and is not distributed, it does not have to be GPLd at all.

Comment: You're quite right, I should have been clearer.